# Reactive value is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I don't know why I cant access reactive value in methods.

```
...
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-contents">
    <datafieldcheckbox class="filterComponents" :filtervalue="filterAll" @call-method="callfilteredproducts"></datafieldcheckbox>
  </div>
</div>
....
    new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data() {
                return {
                    filterAll: this.filtered(),
                    dataCategory : ["data"]
                }
            },
.....
    methods: {
                filtered() {
                    console.log("this.data", this.dataCategory)  // Got undefined insted of getting value.
                }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `filtered` method is called, `data` isn't fully setup yet. It makes sense that `dataCategory` is not available. Instead, call it in `created` hook, where data is already available.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filterAll: null,
      dataCategory: ["data"]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    filtered() {
      console.log("this.data", this.dataCategory); // Got undefined insted of getting value.
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.filterAll = this.filtered();
  }
};
```

*( P.S. Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But it does seem wrong. )*

Comment: I'll try this. I want to assign dynamic value in prop at datafieldcheckbox and use that value in another component.